# How to rewrite url to multiple query parameters?

Tags: apache, url, parameters, url-rewriting

How to rewrite a url like:

http://domain.com/class/method/parameter1/parameter2/.../parameterN

to

http://domain.com/index.php?c=class&m=method&p1=parameter1&...&pN=parameterN

The main idea is to create the possibility of using unlimited number of query parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do that with [Apache’s mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ /$1$3?p[]=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But it would definitely be easier to do that with PHP:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
if (count($segments) >= 2) {
    $_GET['class'] = array_shift($segments);
    $_GET['m'] = array_shift($segments);
    $_GET['p'] = $segments;
} else {
    // error
}
```

Then you just need one single rule to rewrite the requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: With the addition of: 
$segments = explode('/', $segments);
and some iteration for the remaining query parameters after:
$_GET['p'] = array_shift($segments);
the simple method you proposed worked like a charm.
Thanks.

Comment: @vbklv: Ah yes, forgot to `explode`.